# Angular dynamic api call

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6

Trying to call a list of apis obtained from first api call

```
loadData() {
  this.http.get(this.firstApi).pipe(
    .map(response => response.ip)
        )
      .subscribe(ip => {
        console.log(ip);

        Observable.forkJoin(
          ip.map(
             g =>
             this.http.get('http://'+ip+':port/api/status')
             .map(response => response.json())
           )
         ).subscribe(res => {
             //THIS WILL LOG GAME RESULTS SUCH AS HITS/PITCHES/STOLENBASES/RUNS...
             let i;
             res.forEach((item, index) => {
               i = index;
               console.log(res[i]);
             })
          })
   });
}
```

The issue is that `ip` is undefined. Any way to solve the issue.

Generally what I need is

Call an api -> returns list of object with ip key and other stuff (ip is relevant).
Call status api (returns a json object) in each of the ip obtained and push the result to an array.

Comment: If `ip` is undefined then debug `response`, it might not have `ip` as a direct key

Comment: the return value of firstApi is an array of objects [{'ip':'192.168.0.1',..},{'ip':'192.168.0.2',..},..]

Comment: Well, an array doesn't have an `ip` property. It only has a `length` property. So response.ip doesn't make sense if response is an array. Everything would be so much clearer if you defined and specified types: `this.http.get<Array<{ip: string;}>>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting confused with `rxjs` map and `Array` map. The map inside `pipe()` is by `rxjs`, you can leverage on this to modify the returned Observable. Array `map` returns a new Array.
I see that you are doing two subscriptions, instead of doing this, you can use `mergeMap` to faltten the returned Obervable. ALso to make Observables for `forkJoin` before hand, this will make the code clear.

```
loadData() {
  this.http.get(this.firstApi).pipe(
    mergeMap((firstResponse) => {
      let obsevablesArray = firstResponse.map((eachOb) => this.http.get(`http://${eachOb.ip}:port/api/status`)); //  map from Array prototype
      return forkJoin(...obsevablesArray)
    })
  ).subscribe((dataFromAllIp) => {
      console.log(dataFromAllIp);
      // do the rest of your logic here.
  })
}
```

I have given a similar answer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/forkjoinwithmergemap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Refer if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried the answer given in the stackblitz link. But I get error Property map and foreach does not exist on type Object.

Comment: @Azeeb: The link added in the answer is just for your reference, this doesn't exactly answer your question. For your `.ts` error try adding the return type as advised by @JB Nizet. You can try it just here: `this.http.get<Array<{ip: string;}>>(this.firstApi)`

Comment: you can have an interface which contains all the props returned by `firstApi` and make the return type as an array of that interface

Answer (score 0):

Is there something to obtain below mentioned scenario

Call an api -> returns list of object with ip key and other stuff (ip is relevant). Call status api (returns a json object) in each of the ip obtained and push the result to an array.

Whenever an api return push the result to an array?